# Deactivate A Trigger

Tags: trigger

I have an old trigger in my org that is no longer used and is throwing errors. I have tried to deactivate it in the sandbox and send it to production as a change set but it fails validation. When I try to comment it out in production I am getting errors and not allowed to save it.  Any help would be great.

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert, after insert, after update, before update) {
//
//Created Date :   15 Feb' 2016
//Task         :   T-476163
//Description  :   Trigger to update the Geolocation fields on Influencer(Contact) object
//
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore){
       if(System.label.Disable_Influencer_Owner_Change == 'false'){
             list<contact> contlist = trigger.new;
             for(contact cont: contlist){
                 cont.InfluencerOwner__c = cont.ownerid;
                 cont.ownerid = System.label.NewOwnerId;
             }
       }
    }

    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore){
     System.debug('####### Before update cont.influencerOwner__c ');

       if(System.label.Disable_Influencer_Owner_Change == 'false'){
             list<contact> oldcontlist = trigger.old;
             list<contact> newcontlist = trigger.new;
             System.debug('####### Before update '+oldcontlist.size());             
             for(contact cont: newcontlist){
                 contact oldContact = Trigger.oldMap.get(cont.Id);
                 /*
                 if (cont.InfluencerOwner__c != null && cont.ownerid != cont.influencerOwner__c) {
                     cont.InfluencerOwner__c = cont.ownerid;
                     cont.ownerid = System.label.NewOwnerId;
                 }*/
                  if(cont.influencerOwner__c == null){
                     System.debug('####### cont.influencerOwner__c '+System.label.NewOwnerId);
                     cont.InfluencerOwner__c = cont.ownerid;
                     cont.ownerid = System.label.NewOwnerId;                 
                 }
             }
       }

    }

    if ( Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter ) {
        //ContactTriggerHandler.afterInsert( Trigger.new );
    }
    else if ( Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter ) {
        //ContactTriggerHandler.afterUpdate( Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap );
    }
    else if ( Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore ) {
        //ContactTriggerHandler.beforeUpdate( Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap );
    }

    if(Trigger.isAfter){
        if(checkRecursive.runOnce())
        {
            System.debug('######## Contact trigger Called ');
            System.debug('########System.Label.Disable_Interface_Flow '+System.Label.Disable_Interface_Flow);            
            if('False' == System.Label.Disable_Interface_Flow){
                 System.debug('######## Called syncCustomer code');
                SendAccountUsingRestApi.syncCustomer();
            }
            if(Trigger.isUpdate){
                if('False' == System.Label.DISABLE_PARDOT_ASSIGNMENT_CALL){
                    CustomPARDOT.assignProspectsByContact(Trigger.new);
                }
            }
         if('false' == System.Label.DISABLE_RELATIONSHIP_OWNER_SHARING){
           InfluencerSharingWithRelationshipOwner.sharewithRelationshipOwner(Trigger.new);
         }
         System.debug('::CONTACT SENT TO PARDOT::');

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to comment it out?

Comment: echoing Amanda - also check to see that your test class is also commented out.

Comment: You can't directly edit Apex code in production. You need to tailor your change set to ensure that the deployment succeeds, which may mean altering or deactivating your test classes in the sandbox and deploying them alongside the deactivation of the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005417&type=1

You have to change the dependent test classes to make sure your validation passes.

Sometimes, its hard to do that and if it's urgent then you can use this hack. This hack will make Trigger run only when tests are run, and when actual code is run it will bypass.

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert, after insert, after update, before update) {

    if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
        return;

    }

    //Your old trigger code here

}
```

Comment: clever ..... I hope never to have to do this :-)

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this after so long. I got distracted with other projects.   We have a few old triggers that are no longer used including the one that originally started this thread. They are all failing their test classes and have 0 code coverage. The org itself has about 63% code coverage.  I am not able to deploy the commented out triggers from the sandbox due to the code coverage. If I use Pranay's hack is there anything I need do to in the long term to fix this?  As an admin that has just been starting out on his coding career my skills are limited here.

Comment: If its for long term, don't use any hacks. Go to your sandbox, remove old trigger , write proper test classes and get it going. There is no easy way out.